# How does a lexer generator identify the keywords of a grammar?

Tags: compiler-construction, keyword, lexer

I'm thinking about how to write a lexer generator. I can't think of an simple way to identify the keywords of a language from its grammar..obviously all keywords are terminals, but not all terminals are keywords. For example, in the following simple grammar:
truth_value -> 'true' | 'false';
digit -> '0'..'9';
'true' and 'false' are keywords but '0','1' etc aren't.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most lexer generators require the programmer to write out regular expressions (or something similar) to identify the key words (and other terminals). I've never heard of one that attempted to start from a formal grammar, and figure out the keywords on its own.

For example, here's part of a `.l` file (lex/flex) input file for a calculator I wrote years ago:

```
sqrt    { return SQRT;  }
lg      { return LN2;   }
log     { return LOG;   }
sin     { return SIN;   }
cos     { return COS;   }
tan     { return TAN;   }
pi      { return PI;    }
exit    { return EXIT;  }
prec    { return PREC;  }
print   { return PRINT; }
\?      { return PRINT; }
[ \t]   { ; }

[-+*/=()^] { return yytext[0]; }
\n         { lineno++; return yytext[0]; }
```

Comment: You mean explicitly declare the keywords even though they've been used in some rewrite rules anyway?

Comment: @prophet_on_that: If I understand correctly, yes. See sample in edited answer.